# Centering plots

Tags: alignment

The two plots look like they have been "flushed left". How can I make them appear in the center or centered?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,shadows.blur}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}


    \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{insesgado_svd_100k}
        \caption{Error }
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{sesgado_svd_1M_matlab}
        \caption{Error}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{ $\Lambda$ f $F$.}
    \end{center}    
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Widths of your subimages is to big. Their sum should be equal or les than width of text area!

Comment: Good point! I’ll check it @Zarko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you looking for something like this:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{insesgado_svd_100k}
    \caption{Error }
    \label{fig:mysubfig1}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sesgado_svd_1M_matlab}
    \caption{Error}
    \label{fig:mysubfig2}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{ $\Lambda$ f $F$.}
    \label{fig:myfig}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

From comparison of the mine and yours MWE follows:

- Used is `article` document class since in `standalone` class you can't use floats (without option `varwidth`) and in it you can't see, if the image are horizontal centered in text. Shortly, your MWE doesn't work.
- In the `figure` environment is not used `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}` environment since it insert additional vertical space around images. Instead of it is used `\centering`.
- Sum of the `subfigure`s widths should be equal or better smaller than `\textwidth`. Otherwise they will spill out on the right side of text area (or even page).
- Code is shorter, if you define images widths with with of `subfigure`, i.e. `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{....}`. In this case you can omit command `\centering` inside `subfigure`s.

Comment: @BenVoigt, is now better?

Comment: Yes, much more readable

Comment: @Zarko Thank you so much for this answer. I have fixed all my plot in my thesis TeX document! I really appreciate it

Comment: @NaveganTeX, you are welcome! Happy TeXing!